# Simplifying Sigma Notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, fibonacci-numbers

I am working on the proof on showing the ratio of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers converges to the golden ratio to explain to a student I am tutoring. I am getting to some confusion in a simplification step:
$$\frac{\alpha\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha^{n-i}\beta^i}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha^{n-i}\beta^i}$$
$$=\alpha[1+\frac{\beta^{n}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha^{n-i}\beta^i}]$$
Could somone please explain to me how this simplification occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Write the last term in the upper sum separately: $$\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha^{n-i}\beta^i = \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha^{n-i}\beta^i\right) + \alpha^{n-n}\beta^n$$